# How to get CREATE gorm's data to a variable

Tags: go-gorm

Assume i have the below information to be inserted in the DB.

Assume Table columns are:

```
|ID | Age | Name |
```

Data to be inserted in to DB:

```
var animal = Animal{Age: 99, Name: ""}
db.Create(&animal)
```

When i do this, how can i get the data back to a variable. Does gorm return back the record data we just inserted ? If so, how can i store it to a variable and reuse it.

Example usecase : i want to print the DB generated ID on the console
How do i store the data

Comment: Regarding the commented section below `db.Create(&animal)` here [in documentation](http://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values), I'd expect `animal.ID` to return what you want directly.

Comment: Looks like it from the documentation. Wish there was a way to store into another variable by passing another parameter. Like db.Create(&animal, newAnimal) . This would make sure we have both the data for reference